# Why can't sscanf handle a space-containing string followed by a comma and an integer?

Tags: c, scanf

While trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158875/scanning-in-a-text-file-into-a-linked-list#28159102), I discovered the following strange issue with `sscanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void){
    const char* lit ="George Washington, 2345678";
    char buffer[1024];
    int out = 0;
    memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
    sscanf(lit, "%50[^,]s, %d\n", buffer, &out);
    printf("%s %d\n", buffer, out);
}
```

The output of this code is `George Washington 0`.

**Why is this and how can it be corrected?**

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091284/read-comma-separated-input-with-scanf) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf).

Comment: The format you are looking for is `"%50[^,], %d\n"` -- no `s` is needed.

Comment: This seems to be a fairly common problem (putting a stray `s` after a `%[`